# Statistics and econometrics distance learning

Tags: teaching, econometrics

I would be very glad if someone can point me out to statistics and econometrics distance learning courses like http://www2.statistics.com.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few links:

http://www.stat.tamu.edu/dist/

http://www.stat.colostate.edu/distance_degree.html

http://www.worldcampus.psu.edu/AppliedStatisticsCertificate.shtml

Answer (score 6):

Stanford has some good programs as part of [**SCPD**](http://scpd.stanford.edu/).  In particular, you might be interested in the ["Data Mining and Applications Graduate Certificate"](http://scpd.stanford.edu/public/category/courseCategoryCertificateProfile.do?method=load&certificateId=1209602#searchResults).